# Set VPN connection programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

In my Android application, I would like to set a VPN connection programmatically. Is it possible in Android?  Please let me know some site which gives clear details about the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with Android SDK. However, some manufactures like Motorola have their own flavor of android and in their SDK they have made it possible.