# Android - How can I programmatically add a VPN network

Tags: android

The Settings on Android provides an option to add VPN manually.

Can this be done programmatically through some kind of an API?

I'm not looking for a way to connect to a VPN. I'm only concerned about configuring a VPN profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658493/set-vpn-connection-programmatically-in-android) answer, it is not possible with the Android SDK.

> This is not possible with Android SDK. However, some manufactures like
>   Motorola have their own flavor of android and in their SDK they have
>   made it possible.

Comment: Does Motorola allow for you to use their SDK with non-Motorola devices?

Comment: No the motorola EDM sdk comes bundled with the latest Motorola phones. It cannot be used in other phones. See http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/Secure_and_Flexible_Device_Management_for_Motorola_Devices/ for more detials

Comment: @jack Does the new 4.0 sdk provide any such functionality? I see sone VpnService but not sure if it has this capability

Comment: @Avinash Read http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html, bottom of page

Answer (score 0):

See also this question -- [Create VPN profile on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9718289/1281925). Briefly, we came to the conclusion that it's not only not possible with the Android SDK, but it's not possible even with a hacked SDK unless you have a rooted device (because the VPN profiles are stored via the system KeyStore, so you would need to be running as a system process to add / modify them).

However, there does appear to be a third-party VPN app that at least claims to do this without a rooted device, but it doesn't appear to be open-source and I can't vouch for it (see the comments here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8915).