# Create VPN profile on Android

Tags: android, root, vpn

Is it possible to programmatically create VPN profile on Android (assuming that I have a rooted device)?

If is possible, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should look at the com.android.settings.vpn2 package. There it uses the @hidden KeyStore methods to manipulate VPNs:

- `KeyStore.getInstance().saw(Credentials.VPN)` returns an array of String VPN IDs
- `VpnProfile.decode(KeyStore.getInstance().get(Credentials.VPN + vpn_id))` gets the VPN configuration data for the given VPN ID and decodes it as a VpnProfile object.
- `VpnProfile.put(Credentials.VPN + vpn_id, someVpnProfileInstance.encode())` will create/update a VPN connection with the given ID using the settings in the VpnProfile instance.

However, you will need to execute this as the system process -- otherwise, the KeyStore instance you get will not be connected to the one that the OS uses.

If there is a way to do this *without* a rooted device, I'd be interested in knowing how...

P.S. - There's a similar question here: [How to programmatically create a new VPN interface with Android 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921457/1281925)

Comment: This can be done without rooting the device. Simply gain access to the hidden API and the rest is just a google away.

Comment: @slott how to gain access to the hidden API ?

Comment: http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

Comment: I  tried to  follow the blog but it seems  i am unable to extract  classes.dex from framework.jar    emulator as  well as devices  didnt  have it  even rooted  one.. did i miss  something obvious  ??